# Naming conventions for external resources?

Tags: assets

While we develop games, then we have utilize several external resources, for example

- Image
- Sound
- Animation
- Sprite Sheet

Is there any good naming convention regarding these external resources?

Comment: Aren't file extensions sufficient?

Comment: @Byte56 Please help me to write the question in currently worded.

Comment: Sorry Mahbubur, I'm not sure how it would be reworded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a folder for my sources, i call it `src` and a folder for assets called `assets` which looks like:

```
- Assets
    - Images
    - Sounds
    - Scripts
    - Animations
    - Config (for property files etc.)
    - ... (maybe others regarding the game i'm working on)
```

**EDIT:** And regarding naming conventions for those resources

- Use a period to separate the base file name from the extension in the
  name of a directory or file.
- No white space
- Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period.
- For long file name use hyphen(-)
- Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Comment: +1 for good resource. Can you add naming conventions in your answer?

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman i don't have naming conventions? Not sure to understand what you mean, feel free to edit the answer :-)

Comment: I mean the Images for example, backgroundimage.jpg or backGroundImage.jpg or background-image.jpg. Naming conventions for images and other external resources.

Comment: Ok. I have edited your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can take help from Microsoft's File,Stream,Path and Namespace resources

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx

Also following resource

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of object-oriented folder structures.

```
- Gui
   - HealthBar.png
   - ManaBar.png
   - Layout.xml
- Creatures
  - Elves
    - Elf Sharpshooter
      - Definition.txt
      - Sprite.png
      - Script.as 
    - Elf Fighter
      - Definition.txt
      - Sprite.png
      - Script.as
```

Make sure that the paths are case-sensitive else you will run into problems with everything not windows.

Comment: Well, if you open up 3 files by the name of "Definition.txt", that's a recipe to get confused quickly, because most IDEs/text editors will just display the file name. I like to tell which file is which by just looking at the filename.